# Cannot play audio file on web page

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I am trying to play an audio file when a timer counts down to zero. The problem is that I receive the following message once the code is loaded:

```
HTTP "Content-Type" of "audio/mpeg" is not supported. Load of media resource https://www.xxx.com/sounds/beep.mp3 failed.

All candidate resources failed to load. Media load paused.
```

I am loading the page using jQuery Ajax call. All other HTML and javascript returned by the call works fine.

I have tried multiple .wav and .mp3 files without luck.

The html related to sound is:

```
<audio id="soundSrc">
<source src="/images/beep.mp3"></source>       
</audio>
```

Which is initialized with:

```
var soundFile = $('#soundSrc');
```

It is played with:

```
soundFile[0].play();
```

Comment: Just curious, have you tried testing you code with a WAV file? (just as an additional source of symptom verification)

Comment: @DavidTansey Yes. I originally tried using a .WAV file first and switched to an MP3 on the off-hand chance that was the issue.